# Validate raw_input to a specific form

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
blah = raw_input("here--->")

def validate(time):
    match_val = re.search(r'\d\d:\d\d', time)
    if match_val:
        return time
    else:
        while match_val == False:
            str = raw_input("Enter a correct time HH:MM :   "
            match_val = re.search(r'\d\d:\d\d', str)
    return match_val.group()

print validate(blah)
```

hey, I've been trying to get a specific input from a user and that only that input will count. for example  22:00 , but 222:00 will not pass , or any letters for that matter... but im getting a syntax error on :

```
        match_val = re.search(r'\d\d:\d\d', str)
```

this part.. any ideas?

Comment: the syntax error is because you aren't closing parentheses on the previous line (with the `raw_input`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the line above:

```
str = raw_input("Enter a correct time HH:MM :   "
#                                          here--^
```

Also, please do not name a variable `str`.  Doing so overshadows the [built-in](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#func-str).

Comment: +10000 on not naming the same as builtins ... id say that accounts for 25% of problems posted to SO ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley - And it seems like another 25% has to do with unbalanced parenthesis or similar typos. :)

Comment: wow.. thanks.. I'll work on these